# find the cubic in x where the values of the functions are 0,0,4,8 in the values of x=1,-2,-1,2

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Find the cubic on x white m which vanishes when x=1 and x=-2 and has values 4&8 when x=-1 and x=2. It is in the book of an excursion in mathematics olympiad book.

Comment: Let $$f(x)=ax^3 +bx^2+cx+d $$ , you have four equation and four variable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: A cubic polynomial can be factored into $p(x)=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)$, where $r_i$ are the roots of the polynomial. So your polynomial can be factored into $p(x)=a(x-1)(x+2)(x-r)$ where $r$ is the third root of the polynomial. Now if you plug in the values given, you will have two equations that you can solve for $a$ and $r$ in.

Answer (score 1):

A cubic polynomial can be written in the form $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

You are told four points which the cubic passes through, $(1,0),(-2,0),(-1,4),(2,8)$.

Reworded, the fact that the cubic passes through the point $(1,0)$ implies that $p(1)=0$, that is to say $a\cdot 1^3 + b\cdot 1^2 + c\cdot 1+d = 0$.

In the same manner, we can rewrite all of the equations implied by the cubic passing through these points as the system of equations:

$$\begin{cases} a\cdot 1^3+b\cdot 1^2 + c\cdot 1 + d = 0\\ a\cdot (-2)^3 + b\cdot (-2)^2 + c\cdot (-2)+d = 0\\
a\cdot (-1)^3 + b\cdot (-1)^2 + c\cdot (-1)+d = 4\\
a\cdot 2^3 + b\cdot 2^2 + c\cdot 2+d = 8\end{cases}$$

or by simplyfing:

$$\begin{cases} a + b+c+d=0\\ -8a+4b-2c+d=0\\ -a+b-c+d=4\\ 8a+4b+2c+d=8\end{cases}$$

We can rewrite this as a matrix equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&1&1\\-8&4&-2&1\\-1&1&-1&1\\8&4&2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\4\\8\end{bmatrix}$$

From here, you may use your favorite method (*e.g. matrix inverse, gaussian elimination, elementary matrices, ...*) to solve the matrix equation for the unknown vector, and thus the constants $a,b,c,d$, thereby finding the equation of the cubic.

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange's interpolation formula,
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{(x+2)(x-1)(x-2)}{(-1+2)(-1-1)(-1-2)}\times 4 + \frac{(x+2)(x+1)(x-1)}{(2+2)(2+1)(2-1)}\times 8 \\
&= \frac{2}{3}(x+2)(x-1)(2x-1)
\end{align*}